# How can i plot multiple plots with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I do have a plot_list with almost 300 plots. Is there a way to plot all the plots from the array with plotly? I don't know how to create a subplot with so many plots.

Here is my code:

```
plot_list = list()
for(i in 2:length(colnames.no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009)){

  # Create columns for buffer.data.frame to plot
  first.column.buffer <- no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009$`country name`
  second.column.buffer <- round(as.numeric(unlist(no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009[134])))
  third.column.buffer <- round(as.numeric(unlist(no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009[i])))
  colnames.no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009 <- colnames(no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009)

  # Create buffer.data.frame to plot
  buffer.data.frame <- cbind.data.frame(first.column.buffer, second.column.buffer, third.column.buffer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(buffer.data.frame) <- (c("c", "b", "a"))

  # Safe plot in array
  p <- ggplot(buffer.data.frame, aes(a, b, name = c)) + ggtitle("Title") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    xlab(colnames.no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009[i]) + ylab(colnames.no.na.work.df.worldbank.2009[134]) + geom_point() 
  plot_list[[i-1]] = p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the items in a list enclosed in divs so you can control style.
Display it using uiOutput()

```
# You have to provide the plotly plot_list to the function
output$all_plots <- shiny::renderUI({
    all_plots <- list()
    for (n in seq_along(plot_list)) {
        all_plots[[n]] <- div(style="padding:5px; margin: 5px;",plot_list[[n]])
    }
    return(all_plots)
})
```

Comment: Thank you MiguelS. I don't get it right! I added my code to my question above. I get different errors like "Error in output$all_plots <- shiny::renderUI({ : 
  object 'output' not found"